# How to combine two tables into one whole, changing the positions according to the selected variables?

Tags: php, arrays

How to combine two tables into one whole, changing the positions according to the selected variables?

exp:

```
$number1=402-1;
for( $x = 1; $x <= 400; $x++ )
{
  $number1=$number1-1;
  require_once"dbmysql.php";
  here the query and the extraction of variables
  "SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE id='".$r['id']."' AND x='".$number1."'"
  $Array1[] = array
    ("number1"=>"".$number1."","r"=>"".$rw['dbmysql_variables']."")
}
$number2=402-1;
for( $x = 1; $x <= 400; $x++ )
{
  $number2=$number2-1;
  require_once"dbmysql2.php";
  here the query and the extraction of variables
  "SELECT * FROM tableB WHERE id='".$r['id']."' AND x='".$number2."'"
  $Array2[] = array
    ("number"=>"".$number2."","r"=>"".$rw['dbmysql2_variables']."")
}
 sort($Array1); 
 sort($Array2);
 $result = array_unique(array_merge($Array1,$Array2), SORT_REGULAR);
 foreach ( $result as &$this ) 
{
    echo'<a title="'.$this["number"].'" href="?'.$this["r"].'"><div style="background-image:url('.$this["r"].');" class="xxx">'.$this["number"].'</div></a>';
    
}
unset( $this );
```

How to combine both tables into one table and that variables are extracted in both according to the query to the database, but so as not to exceed 400 $this["number"]? and that the variables of both were in one?

Comment: $number1=402-1 **=401**

Comment: this not a point

Comment: But why? Are you creating a maze? you should keep it simple when asking

Comment: $number1=402-1 = **401** but $number1=$number1-1; = **400**, yes something like maze

Comment: use --$number1 or $number -- .   
$i = 1;
$x = $i++;
echo $x; // prints 1
$x = ++$i;
echo $x; // prints 3

Comment: you not helping

Comment: require_once"dbmysql.php"; this should be called only once outside the loops also comment out non code text

Comment: organize your code and you will get help